# Манихейство

Tags: семантика

Будьте добры дать толкование. 
К примеру: "манихейские представления о ... "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От учения Мани, персидск. пророка. Построено на гностическом (тайном, сокровенном) прочтении, понимании и объяснении Торы (Библии евреев), включены элементы зороастризма.

Answer (score 1):

Манихейство - синкретическая дуалистическая религия,  учение об изначальности и неистребимости зла в окружающем мире. Человек  двойственен: творение дьявола, он сотворен все же по образцу небесного "светлого первочеловека"  содержит в себе и частицы света, которые человек и должен спасать от власти материи. Это спасение осуществимо в условиях строжайшего аскетизма: воздержания от мясной и некоторых видов растительной пищи, полного безбрачия, избегания контакта с «тленными» вещами.